# How to export a razor view to word in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, ms-word

In my project, I have many actions return views. The views are simple, they just render Html by ViewModel, no images,no javascripts,no flashs, only simple html tags(table,h2,title). I want to have a button at the bottom of the page or on the top,  and exprot the view result to ms word. I tried several ways,

here is  2 ways I tried but all failed:

- http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/aspnet/threads/228074/exporting-web-page-to-word-in-asp.netc
- http://www.revium.com.au/articles/sandbox/aspnet-mvc-convert-view-to-word-document/

So is there any easy way to do it? 
I find some thrid party code can solve this problem,but it need append string by hand, I have too many pages to do so it is too much work by this way.

Comment: please post what have you tried so far ? and what is your error ?

Answer (score 0):

```
string htmlString = this.RenderActionResultToString(PartialView("_feedbackInExcel", feedbackModel));

            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=EFFReport.doc");
            Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
            Response.Write(htmlString);
```